# Compiling a Qt application in order to get better debuginfos (Linux)

Tags: c++, linux, qt, debugging

I downloaded [FabariaGest source code](http://www.codelinsoft.it/sito/download/categoria-linux/categoria-linux-fabariagest/fabaria-gest-source-code.raw) then to compile it you have to run:

on qt 4 systems:

```
cmake -DMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=directory -DWANT_QT4=ON -DWANT_QWT=ON
```

on qt5 systems:

```
cmake -DMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=directory -DWANT_QT5=ON -DWANT_QWTQT5=ON
```

When it finishes, you run

```
# make install
```

Since I get a segmentation fault when I start the software, I tried to run

```
cd /opt/fabaria_gest
gdb fabaria_gest
run
backtrace
```

but I only get

```
[user@localhost fabaria_gest]$ gdb fabaria_gest
GNU gdb (GDB) Fedora 7.9.1-19.fc22
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from fabaria_gest...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /opt/fabaria_gest/fabaria_gest 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
Detaching after fork from child process 7246.
[New Thread 0x7fffe0798700 (LWP 7244)]

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004f568c in QBasicAtomicInteger<int>::load() const ()
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00000000004f568c in QBasicAtomicInteger<int>::load() const ()
#1  0x0000000000502a92 in QtPrivate::RefCount::ref() ()
#2  0x0000000000502e37 in QString::QString(QString const&) ()
#3  0x00000000006b9709 in _ZL13getSystemInfov ()
#4  0x00000000006bc29f in main ()
(gdb) 
#0  0x00
```

What can I do to recompile the software in order to get better debuginfos? Setting `set follow-fork-mode` in GDB did not help

Comment: Try `gdb ./fabaria_gest` in your build directory (which should run the build version) rather than `gdb fabaria_gest` (which should run the installed version). Stripping from debugging symbols is a usual part of the `install` make target.

Comment: `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ...` might also help, but then again, it already shows the function name, and it should be easy to deduce which line in that function is failing.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen could you fill an answer so i can give you the green mark?

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ...
```

will instruct cmake to generate debug information, which should make the backtrace easier to read.

Comment: To just generate the debug info (hopefully without altering codegen) you should use `RelWithDebInfo`; using `Debug` disables optimizations and enable several debugging aids, which may make regular bugs more evident, but may hide heisenbugs which only happen in the release build.

Comment: I'd say if you can reproduce the bug, try with normal `Debug` first because you'll likely get better backtraces. But that's good to know if it's one of those bugs that disappears when you enable debugging.